# How to update Select Option drop down menu with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this code below to create a `GET/Import` button on my form. I want to `import NAME` and `AGE` for my users.

This is my jQuery script to get values:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.button').click(function() {
            $.get('values.php', function(data) {
                result = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("input[name='nick_name']").val(result.avaname);
                $("option[name='age']").val(result.tavaage);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my form with "**input field** for `name`" and "**select option menu** for `age`":

```
<tr>
<td><label>Name <span>(nickname)</span></label><input type="text" value="<? echo $nick_name;?>" id="nick_name" class="" name="nick_name" /></td>

<td><label>Age</label><select id="age" class="" name="age" ><option value="<? echo $age; ?>" ><? echo $age; ?></option>
<option value="18" >18</option>
<option value="19" >19</option>
<option value="20" >20</option>
<option value="21" >21</option>
<option value="22" >22</option>
<option value="23" >23</option>
<option value="24" >24</option>
<option value="25" >25</option>
<option value="26" >26</option>
<option value="27" >27</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<input class="button" type="button" value="Get/Import" />
```

**My problem is**:  When I press this button then the input field for `name` updates and shows the `name` as expected but the `age` select option is still empty?

My question is: How can I updates/add option values for my select menu for `age`?
(I know in my jQuery script LINE NR 8 is incorrect, but that's what I have tried)

All help will be highly appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`$("#age option[value='"+result.tavaage+"']").attr("selected","selected");`

Comment: Wonderful! Even with selected, selected!! Exactly what I needed :) Thank a MILLION, you saved me :D

Comment: Im using this code and it works if the NEW option value already exists in select list. If the value is NOT in the list then then NEW value will not be added with this CODE. Is it any way around this? So it can make a new select option if it is not already in the drop list.

Comment: yes write this: `if($("#age option[value='"+result.tavaage+"']").length > 0){$("#age option[value='"+result.tavaage+"']").attr("selected","selected");} else{$("#age").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+result.tavaage+"'>"+result.tavaage+"</option>");}`

Comment: Incredible... Works like a CHARM :D Cant ask for more :) I will add you to my favorits ;D

Comment: @Cyborg thank u.. u can ping me for doubts i will definitely help u

Comment: Hi mate, Can you please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824782/ ? I need your help. Thank you

Comment: Now I got a other problem. It looks like you cant use jquery.min.js with WordPress? I started a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838858/

Comment: @Cyborg I think you have got solution.

Comment: I got a solution which is working for now. But its not preferred to edit WP CORE files. So Im afraid I will need to do it again when WP updates again. It should be possible to do the same using functions.php for my Theme..

Answer (score 1):

Try these

```
$('#age').attr('value',result.tavaage);
```

OR

```
$("#age").val(result.tavaage);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the value to `select` element, not to the `option`.

```
$("#age").val(result.tavaage);
```