# How to sort/filter values from Array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to foreach values of this array:

My CODE:

```
<?php

print_r(array_filter($matches));

?>
```

Result of this CODE:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
      [0] => Age:                     // Name
      [1] => 22 Yrs.                  // Value
      [2] => Ethnicity:               // Name
      [3] => Caucasian                // Value
      [4] => Location:                // Name
      [5] => London, United Kingdom   // Value
```

Now I want to get this values separated/filtered like:

```
$location = 'London, United Kingdom';
$age = '22 Yrs.';
```

So I can simply do a `echo $age;`

**Remark**: In some cases the user have NOT set all the values. So its not guaranteed that Value  Age always exists in this array. Therefore I need something like:

If "Age:" is found in array then $age =

How can I do this? I have totally 33 names and 33 values in this array and need to filter them all based on IF statement to be sure that the value is the right value.

**Result** of `var_dump($matches);` :

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(66) { 
         [0]=> string(202) " Age: " 
         [1]=> string(157) " 22 Yrs. " 
         [2]=> string(196) " Ethnicity: " 
         [3]=> string(146) " Caucasian " 
         [4]=> string(195) " Location: " 
         [5]=> string(175) " London, United Kingdom "
```

**Result** of `var_export($matches);` :

```
array ( 
     0 => array ( 
         0 => ' Age: ', 
         1 => ' 22 Yrs. ', 
         2 => ' Ethnicity: ', 
         3 => ' Caucasian ',
         4 => ' Location: ', 
         5 => ' London, United Kingdom ',
```

Im newbie so if you have a better ways to do this then please advice.
Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: your array look very weird

Comment: Better way to do this is to try to hydrate the array using associative keys vs numeric values. Otherwise you will be in mapping hell trying to map a key to a specific context (key 0 = age). Try to hydrate the array, so it looks like: `['age'] => '22 years', ['ethnicity'] => ['Caucasian']` etc...

Comment: How on earth have you managed to get your array like this?

Comment: @Daniel @Emilio: I have updated my CODE. Previously I was doing wrong. Cause `$matches` is already a **array** so it was wrong using `$entry = array($matches);`

Comment: as @MikePurcell you should match key=>values, is the correct and better way to do.

Comment: @MikePurcell: Can I somehow tell this array to Use Array number: 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14 and so on as Labels/Names of Values and use: 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15 as Values/Results?

Comment: You could, I think that's what @lincb response is eluding too, but I would highly recommend against doing so. You may get it to work out of the gate, but maintaining it could cause some serious headaches down the road.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments above, I would try to modify the `$matches` if at all possible - it would be far easier to work with associative arrays for this use case.

However, taking it on face value that you're stuck with that data structure, here's one probably very naive approach...

this assumes that your data will always come out in the format `[key, value, key, value, ...]`:

```
<?php

// original data
$matches = array(
    array(
        'Age:',
        '22 Yrs.',
        'Ethnicity:',
        'Caucasian',
        'Location:',
        'London, United Kingdom',
        'Location:',
    )
);

// chunk $matches sub-array into pairs
// we want each chunk to contain two elements,
// the first will be the key and the second will be the value
$chunks = array_chunk($matches[0], 2);

// apply a callback to each array element
$pairs = array_map(function($pair) {

    // some basic error checking...
    // if the matches subarray count is uneven for some reason

    if (count($pair) !== 2) {
        return array();
    }

    // assign each element in the pair
    list($key, $val) = $pair;


    // some basic key normalisation
    // remove non alpha chars and lowercase
    $key = strtolower($key);
    $key = preg_replace('/\W+/', '', $key);

    // return a key value pair 
    return array($key => $val);

}, $chunks);

// iterate over the pairs
// and extract into the current scope...
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    extract($pair);
}

// and you should now be able to echo your values
echo $age;
echo $ethnicity;
echo $location;
```

Result:

```
22 Yrs.
Caucasian
London, United Kingdom
```

Hope this helps :) To reiterate, I would really recommend restructuring the original data structure because the above solution is hardly optimal.

Comment: I copy pasted your CODE and it worked. But when i removed: `$matches = array(
    array(
     'Age:',
        '22 Yrs.',
        'Ethnicity:',
        'Caucasian',
        'Location:',
        'London, United Kingdom',
        'Location:',
    )
);` **and** used my `$matches` as array then it didn't work :( Your code is very close to what I need.

Comment: I have updated my question. I cant still get your code to work with my array `$matches`. But I see it works with your array. Can you please see me updated question with `var_dump($matches)`?

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. The arrays should be the same. I based mine on your text. Can you post your `$matches` array for comparison? Are you getting an error or WSOD?

Comment: I can see the difference between your Array and my Array. My Array contains **white_spaces/space** in beginning and ending of all names and values. Please see my `var_dump($matches);` and compare it with your `var_dump($matches);`.

Comment: This shouldn't matter - I've allowed for that. The line `$key = preg_replace('/\W+/', '', $key);` removes any non alpha characters from the string before assigning it to `$key`. So, `" Age: "` becomes `'Age'`, and so on. So the end result should be the same. Do you get an error or blank screen when running with your own array, or what is the output?

Comment: The screen is completely white. No ERROR and No Result. Hmmm.. that is amazing.. Your Array Work and my Array don't Work.. Can it be cause my Array imports DATA from other Document?

Comment: okay, you have a white screen of death... I guess you have a syntax error then. add the following two lines to the top of your script, right after the opening `<?php ` tag: 

`error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);`

this will enable strict error checking and display all errors on screen. you are recommended to always enable these when developing.

Comment: Thank you for this useful TIP. I enabled the error reporting and now it says: `Undefined variable: age - Undefined variable: ethnicity - Undefined variable: location`

Comment: Okay, the data is different somehow. Can you `var_export($match)` your data and post the result?

Comment: I have Updated my question and inserted the `var_export($matches);` data.

Comment: Is this line the same as the example in your code? `$chunks = array_chunk($matches[0], 2);`. Note the `[0]`, we're (sloppily) dereferencing the first element in the `$matches` array in the above example. How and where is `$matches` originally coming from anyway?

Comment: Yes the `$chunks = arr..` is in my file. I copy pasted your CODE and tried and it worked. then I deleted your definition of Array `$matches` and replaced it with my code to get my `$matches`. And now the page is blank and saying: `Undefined variable: age ..`. `$matches` is a result of using `file_get_contents` and get specified results from that file.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you're working with the array that directly contains the data, unlike your output example that shows 3 nested arrays.

```
for($i=0; $i<(count($matches)/2); $i++){
 $label = substr($matches[$i*2],0,-1);
 $output[$label] = $matches[$i*2+1];
}
```

This will make $output an associative array, addressable like this:

```
echo($output["Age"]);
```

Unfortunately, it's impossible as far as I know to make it into individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

Could be more easy try to use separately arrays, eg.

```
$Age = Array ( 
    [0] => 22,
    [1] => 33
);

$Ethnicity = Array ( 
    [0] => "Caucasian",
    [1] => "Other"
);

$Location= Array ( 
    [0] => "London, United Kingdom",
    [1] => "Germany"
);
```