# How to foreach Key -> Value - PHP?

Tags: php

I have a array named `$matches` below you can see a

**Result of** `print_r(array_filter($matches));`

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [0] => Age: 
    [1] => 22 Years 
    [2] => Ethnicity: 
    [3] => Caucasian 
    [4] => Location: 
    [5] => London, United Kingdom
```

and **Result of** `var_dump($matches);`

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> array(66) { 
    [0]=> string(202) " Age: " 
    [1]=> string(157) " 22 Years " 
    [2]=> string(196) " Ethnicity: " 
    [3]=> string(146) " Caucasian " 
    [4]=> string(195) " Location: " 
    [5]=> string(175) " London, United Kingdom "
```

So here the structure here is Key -> Value, Key -> Value,..

As you noticed all Keys(Value Names) ends with a `:`

**The result I want**:

```
echo $age;         // Should result: 22 Years
echo $ethnicity;   // Should result: Caucasian
echo $location;    // Should result: London, United Kingdom
```

How to foreach Array number 0,2,4 as value names?

And hot to set Array number 1,2,5 as their result?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results.

Comment: Is each array in the same order?

Comment: @Fluffeh: Yes array is always in same order but if user have NOT set Age: then string[0] will show **Ethnicity:** and [1] will show **Caucasian**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort/filter values from Array PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824782/how-to-sort-filter-values-from-array-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to just remap and things are going to alternate, try:

```
function remap_alternating(array $values) {
    $remapped = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($values) - 1; $i += 2) {
        $remapped[trim($values[$i], ": ")] = trim($values[$i + 1], " ");
    }
    return $remapped;
}
```

Then you can use

```
$mapped = remap_alternating($matches[0]);

foreach($mapped as $key => $val) {
    echo "<p>$key = $val</p>";
}
```

I set $matches to this:

```
$matches = array(
    array ( " Age: ", " 22 Years ", " Ethnicity: ", " Caucasian ", " Location: ", " London, United Kingdom " )
);
```

and it prints:

Age = 22 Years

Ethnicity = Caucasian

Location = London, United Kingdom

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but unfortunately couldn't get it to work :( I got this **ERROR**: `Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array`

Comment: that is odd, because I didn't use `substr()`

Comment: I'll take a look at this when I get home.

Comment: updated this, it now works according to the information provided.

Comment: Thats really awesome! I tried your code and it works great! The only last ting Im missing is there a way to do like: `echo $age;` and the result should be **22 Years** ? I tried a `var_dump($mapped);` and it says: `["Age: "]=> string(137) "21 Years"` I guess its possible to get the results I want? Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: you should use $mapped["Age:"], arrays are your friend, I promise.

Comment: Thats a good idea. If this is possible then its the best solution I guess. I tried now with: `echo $mapped["Age: "];` but it dont show anything. I tried also `var_dump($mapped["Age: "])` it says `NULL`. What Im doing wrong?

Comment: I trimmed off the  spaces and : so try `$mapped["Age"]`

Comment: Now I can see why I cant get it to work. Its cause I have a lot of HTML codes saved in this values/array. I saw this when I saw the source code in browser now.. Should I use `strip_tags` in your code? How to correctly remove all HTML?

Comment: That's a different question. If I solved this question, upvote, and accept, then ask a NEW question for a different idea! :)