# jQuery conflict! Shows White Screen on POST EDIT page for WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a made a small jQuery script to import values from other file and insert this values in WordPress POST page as Custom Meta Tags.

When I Create A New Post the form is shown below the Post content area and every thing works 100%.

**The problem is** if I press "Edit Post" Button/link then it loads the Post Edit page but nothing is shown. Just a White screen loads, so I cant Edit this Post.

Here is my Script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<input name="file" type="text" id="file">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.button').click(function() {
            var val = $('#file').val();
            $.get('import.php', {file: val}, function(data) {            
                result = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("input[name='nick_name']").val(result.name);
                $("input[name='work_city']").val(result.location);

            });
        });
    });
    </script>

<input type="button" class="button" value="GET/IMPORT">
```

I also tried to add this script (after jquery.min.js):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Then Edit Post page worked but I could not use my custom form/button.

**My question is:** How can I load this Script without getting any conflict with WordPress Edit Post page?

**If I remove:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

From my script then All pages load OK but then my custom made form/button don't work.

**LATEST UPDATE: I GOT IT WORKING :D :D :D**
Just testing when or where I should load this script to get my results successfully. I started editing /wp-admin/admin-header.php (I know its NOT recommended to edit CORE files but Im just doing it for debuggig!) First of all I inserted the jQuery script that Im using on Line 1 before opening of

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Then I went to **POST NEW** page, I could see some different in font sizes but the function I wanted was there, I could use my button. So I opened **EDIT POST** page and I could see the EDIT PAGE! Now EDIT PAGE is working also. Finally I figured out if I insert this jQuery script in beginning on `LINE 59 in /wp-admin/admin-header.php` then every thing **works 100%** :D The design CSS looks good and the functionality is there!

Now I need help to insert/paste this script to LINE 59 in admin-header.php How can I do that using functions.php?

Comment: Why are you including jquery again? If wordpress has already loaded it then your plugin doesn't need too.

Comment: Did you check the page with firebug? Are there error on the firebug console?

Comment: @dciso: I wish I didn't need to use it. But as I mentioned above if I remove this script then Edit Post page worked but I could not use my custom form/button :( And if I include this script then I can use my form/button on **POST NEW** page but then **EDIT POST** page shows BLANK.

Comment: @elpeter: Im newbie and don't know how to check with firebug? How should I do that?

Comment: Are you using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to load your custom JS? If not, you should.  It's the WordPress way to do it, and it allows you to define dependencies (like jQuery) for your script.

Comment: @PatJ: That sounds wise. But how to do it? I need to include this script on POST NEW and EDIT POST pages only. Should it be done in functions.php? I would highly appreciate if you could give a sample? Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off this seems like a bad thing to be doing editing the wordpress core. But if you want to do this, don't include jQuery again. And don't use the $ sign, see this example:

```
jQuery(".SomeClass").click(function(){
    console.log("Some Text");
});

//Therefore you could do something like this
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('.button-test-class').click(function() {
             //Do what you want here, for this we'll write some text to the console
             console.log("Some Text");
        });
  });
</script>

<input type="button" class="button-test-class button" value="Button Test">
```

Answer (score 0):

How to add scripts The WordPress Way:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pjso_my_scripts' );
function pjso_my_scripts() {
    $handle = 'script_name';
    $src = '/path/to/script.js';
    $deps = array( 
        'jquery',
    );
    // add any other dependencies to the array, using their $handle
    $ver = 'x.x';  // if you leave this NULL, 
                   // then it'll use WordPress's version number
    $in_footer = true; // if you want it to load in the page footer
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
}
```

To do it only on the Edit Post screen in the backend, you can use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook combined with `get_current_screen()`:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'pjso_my_scripts' );
function pjso_my_scripts() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( 'post' != $screen->base || 'edit' != $screen->parent_base ) {
        return; // bail out if we're not on an Edit Post screen
    }
    $handle = 'script_name';
    $src = '/path/to/script.js';
    $deps = array( 
        'jquery',
    );
    // add any other dependencies to the array, using their $handle
    $ver = 'x.x';  // if you leave this NULL, 
                   // then it'll use WordPress's version number
    $in_footer = true; // if you want it to load in the page footer
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
}
```

That *should* work, though I haven't tested it.

This code can go in your theme's `functions.php` file, or you could [write a custom plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) so that it will persist across any future theme changes.

#### References

- [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) -- note the list of scripts that WP automatically loads, which includes jQuery
- [`get_current_screen()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen)